# Html email template not working in gmail correctly

Tags: web, gmail, google-web-designer

I have a email template which is working fine. But when i check in mobile gmail app
it is taking 15px margin from left and right side. i am not using the `<body>` tag because gmail replace it.

So how can i remove that margin and show template in full width

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add body tag and add these attributes to it

```
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important; -moz-text-size-adjust:none !important; -ms-text-size-adjust:none !important; margin:0px; padding:0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -moz-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;">
```